# Combine and fill a Pandas Dataframe with the single row of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

If I have two dataframes:

#### df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,15,30,45], 'B':[17,33,23,10,12]})


    A   B
0  10  17
1  20  33
2  15  23
3  30  10
4  45  12
```

#### df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':['cat'], 'D':['dog'], 'E':['emu'], 'F':['frog'], 'G':['goat'], 'H':['horse'], 'I':['iguana']})


     C    D    E     F     G      H       I
0  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
```

How do I combine the two dataframes and fill `df1` whereby each row is a replicate of `df2` ?

Here is what I have so far. The code works as intended, but if I were to have hundreds of columns, then I would anticipate there would be a much easier way than my current method:

#### Current Code:

```
df1 = df1.assign(C = lambda x: df2.C[0],
                 D = lambda x: df2.D[0],
                 E = lambda x: df2.E[0],
                 F = lambda x: df2.F[0],
                 G = lambda x: df2.G[0],
                 H = lambda x: df2.H[0],
                 I = lambda x: df2.I[0])
```

#### Expected output:

```
    A   B    C    D    E     F     G      H       I
0  10  17  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
1  20  33  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
2  15  23  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
3  30  10  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
4  45  12  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with `Series` by first row:

```
df = df1.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
print (df)
    A   B    C    D    E     F     G      H       I
0  10  17  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
1  20  33  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
2  15  23  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
3  30  10  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
4  45  12  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
```

Comment: Thankyou - this worked as intended

Answer (score 3):

Use a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)?

```
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Output:

```
    A   B    C    D    E     F     G      H       I
0  10  17  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
1  20  33  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
2  15  23  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
3  30  10  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
4  45  12  cat  dog  emu  frog  goat  horse  iguana
```

Comment: I get the error message: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: @pylos if you use `how='cross'`, this shouldn't happen, please double-check your command

Comment: still presents a problem, check this: https://i.imgur.com/kg1tfyd.png

Comment: This worked for me without issue.